# Get property from JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json, gwt

I can't get property from JSONObject even I can see it in the eclipse inspector

http://postimg.org/image/a067xzlrh/

```
                JSONObject table= new JSONObject(e.get(i));
                JSONObject td = ((JSONObject) test.get("td"));
                JSONObject first = ((JSONObject) td.get("0"));
                JSONValue classList = first.get("classList");
```

It works fine for the first three calls, but the last line (first.get("classList")) always returns null 
even it has value in the inspector as you can see in the above image

Comment: Could you post your entire JSON object?

Comment: link on picture does not open

Comment: abbr: ""
accessKey: ""
accessKeyLabel: ""
align: ""
attributes: [object MozNamedAttrMap]
axis: ""
*barLeft: <td style="height:" class="jSBarLeft jSBarLeft_0 ui-widget-header ui-state-active">6</td>
*barTop: <td class="jSBarTop jSBarTop_0 ui-widget-header ui-state-active">F</td>
baseURI: "http://network.freightos.local:8888/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!freightRate/FreightRateQuote/new"
bgColor: ""
cellIndex: 6
ch: ""
chOff: ""
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: [object NodeList]
children: [object HTMLCollection]
classList:  ui-state-highlight
className: " ui-state-highlight"

Comment: I'm using JQuery.sheet library that generate me such an JavaScriptObject